# submit button not working when generated from AJAX

Tags: asp.net-core

I got an ASP NET Core RazorPage having a button which asynchronously replaces a part of the given HTML using an AJAX request.
Besides some text content it renders another button which is intended to post back the side when clicked. It is surrounded by a form element.
However, clicking the button I receive an HTTP 400 with the information "This page isn't working" (Chrome). Other browsers like Firefox return an HTTP 400 as well.

The relevant HTML with the button which has been created by the AJAX call is the one below:

```
<form method="post">
<button class="btnIcon" title="Todos" id="btnTodos" formaction="PersonManagement/Parts/MyPageName?handler=PerformTodos">Execute action</button>
</form>
```

As the url exists (I doublechecked it using the browser with a simple GET) I wonder whether the issue could be due to some security settings along with the browser or is there anything I am perhaps missing out here?

Thank you for any hint

Answer (score 0):

Two things here first add this attribute to your form **asp-antiforgery="true"**, then send it's value to the server in your AJAX post request.

jQuery magic starts here :)

token: $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val(),

Antiforgery is ON by default since .net core 2.0 (as far as I remember), so if you do AJAX post you need to send the antiforgery token with each request.

Let us know if it helps. Spread knowledge don't hide it just for yourself :P

Comment: Thank you Stoyan for your input. However, perhaps I did not explain my scenario specific enough. I do not face issues executing the AJAX call which is triggered by the first button. This works well for me as I already include the required token. 
The JQuery success: function at the client also is being executed like a charm and manipulates the html as I need it to. 
To post back the page to the PageModel in a "normal", means synchronous manner. 

THIS is what does not work for me but leads to the 404. In other words, the synchronous call from the dynamically generated button fails.

Comment: ..which comes into my mind is whether it perhaps is necessary to somehow add the token code you mention to my button which fails or to its surrounding form?

Comment: All right, I see... sorry I did not analyze the complete case. Does your "AJAX return" injects only dynamically generated button or a complete form containing within the button which triggers the "second" post back?

Comment: Probably you would have to add the token as well, as your code behaves a lot like code insertion / cross scripting attack and this is the main reason for the tokenization to exists.

Comment: What message you get on your console while you are debugging you app and you fire-up the dynamic button?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I came across a very interesting article from Matthew Jones at https://exceptionnotfound.net/using-anti-forgery-tokens-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages/ about Anti-Forgery Tokens in Razor pages. Worth reading, indeed.

However, independently from that article what solved my issue was simply not to add the <form .. element at the client-side, but already at the server-side. As there is no need for me to explicitly adding it at the client-side, but only the button itself, this is a solution for me which works properly.

A brief summary of my scenario now:

1. There is a Razor Page containing usual cshtml content along with a <form method="post"..
2. Some anchor elements also are included, one is triggering a JQuery AJAX call to the server
3. The JQuery call comes back from the server with some additional HTML  including the post button which which I add to the existing HTML.
4. The button is being rendered inside the now already existing

   Clicking the button causes the page to post back in the wanted manner and executes the handler as intended.

Thanks again Stoyan for your input and help with that.